# Python Nested Loop Patterns

Tags: python, loops, nested

`for i in range(6):

    for j in range(9):

         if (i+j)%2 == 0:

             _star = "*"

         else:

             _star = "*"

         print(_star, end="")

    print()`

My output needs to be the left one:          My output now is on the right:

> ```
>                     ***** ****           *********  
>                     ***** *  *           ********* 
>                     ***** *  *           ********* 
>                     ***** *  *           ********* 
>                     ***** ****           *********
> ```

Comment: Please add all information in your question. Comments are not for describing your problem.

Comment: Any recommendations or advice to help me out?

Comment: Is that really what your pattern should be? Please cross check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put your expected output on 2d area, and check out `*` and `space` is on what function.

```
def star_or_space(i, j):
    # vertical line
    if j == 5:
        return ' '
    # second box area
    if 1 <= i <= 3 and 7 <= j <= 8:
        return ' '
    return '*'

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(10):
        _star = star_or_space(i, j)
        print(_star, end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have two patterns this "***** ****" OR this "***** *  *"
at head and tail you are using this ("***** ****") pattern and in between you are using this ("***** *  *") pattern. so below is the simplest logic for you.

```
top_bottom = "***** ****"
in_between = "***** *  *"
rows = 5
for i in range(rows):
    if i == 0 or i == 4:
        print top_bottom
    else:
        print in_between
```